# memory leak in knockout

Tags: internet-explorer, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Part of our application polls for updates and then updates the model with the changes.  It leaks, most noticeably in chrome.  I saw the problem in **IE** when I left the application running for a long period but it's most noticeable in chrome (version of chrome is 19.0.1084.56 m).

There's an example on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JApKE/9/.  Hit the refresh button over and over and you'll see the memory creep up.

We are using v2.1.0 (I saw in a previous question someone had said there was an issue with foreach bindings which was addressed in this release).

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Hmm. I must have clicked that button 200 times now in Chrome, and I don't see any increase in memory usage. If I click it wildly, it will increase, but as soon as I stop clicking for a couple of seconds, it looks like the garbage collector kicks in, and the memory usage drops again.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any noticeable increase in memory usage, anyway this post could be useful, it is about how to manipulate observable array in efficent ways: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/04/knockoutjs-performance-gotcha.html

Answer (score 0):

After clicking many times the memory will grow. but as soon you force the garbage collector to collect the memory will be freed.

You can start collecting by going in on the timeline tab of the chrome developer tools and clicking on start collecting icon.